# New OS running on VirtualBox does not run

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I installed a new OS in VirtualBox running on Ubuntu. It just gives me this message. I do not know why.

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Kalilinux.

VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

Comment: are you using virtualbox in windows?

Comment: I'm using vb in ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Go to the BIOS settings and enable Virtualiztion technology (for me, it's Intel Virtualization). Or you can just use only one processor in your virtualbox settings.

Comment: Tank you for your answer I'm going to bios and enable virtualization and now I'm installing new os 

Comment: If you need more help ask me.

Comment: Really.....tank you ✋✋✋✋✋

Answer (score 1):

In my case I **reduced the amount of RAM allocated for VM**, you can try it out from VM motherboard settings,

If problem persist check for following glitches,

1. You haven't **enabled VT-x in VirtualBox** and it's required for the VM.
       To enable: open vbox, click the VM, click Settings...,    `System->Acceleration->VT-x` check box.
2. You haven't **enabled VT-x in BIOS** and it's required.

   Check your motherboard manual but you basically want to enter your BIOS just after the machine turns on (usually `DEL key, F2, F12` etc) and find something in the CPU area/menu about "Virtualization" and enable it.
3. Your **processor doesn't support VT-x** (eg a Core i3).
       In this case your BIOS and VirtualBox shouldn't allow you to try and enable VT-x (but if they do, you'll likely get a crash in the VM).
4. You're trying to install or boot a 64 bit guest OS.
       I think 64 bit OS requires true CPU pass-through which requires VT-x. (A VM expert can comment on this point).
5. You are **trying to allocate >3GB** of RAM to the VM.
       Similar to the previous point, this requires:

   - a 64 bit host system; and
   - true hardware pass-through i.e. VT-x.